# How to find out if rows are refenced from other tables?

Tags: postgresql, join, foreign-key, union

I have a table named `contacts` (primary key `id`) which is referenced by a number of other tables via foreign keys. When a list of contacts is displayed in the application, I get their primary keys in an array and need to determine if these records could be deleted. This is just used for display, no actual deleting is taking place here.

[Based on this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/80539/2179), I can find out if **one record** can be deleted:

```
(SELECT 1 FROM case_contacts WHERE contact_id = 5000 LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 1 FROM case_payments WHERE contact_id = 5000 LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 1 FROM invoices WHERE contact_id = 5000 LIMIT 1)
-- etc
LIMIT 1;
```

I could run this query for every contact ID I'm given, but that seems very inefficient.

Is there a way to send a single query for multiple contact IDs (up to ~500 at once)? Any kind of result would be fine, including only the IDs that can be deleted, or only the IDs that cannot be deleted, or a result set of `(contact_id, can_be_deleted)`.

---

EDIT: This is what I'm using until I find a more efficient solution:

```
SELECT  c.id
  FROM  contacts c
 WHERE  c.id IN (1,10,20,1557,5000,15057)
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM case_contacts WHERE contact_id = c.id)
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM case_payments WHERE contact_id = c.id)
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM invoices      WHERE contact_id = c.id);
```

Comment: with con as (select id from contact where id in (10,20,5000)), res as (select cp.id from case_payments cp, case_contacts cc, invoices iv where cp.id in (10,20,5000) and cc.id = cp.id and iv.id = cc.id) select c.id from con c left join res r where r.id is null

Comment: @Spike: I don't think that would work. If I'm reading this correctly, `cc.id = cp.id and iv.id = cc.id` compares the `id` columns of the referencing tables and requires them to be the same. Even when I substitute `contact_id`, it would require a match in *all* the referencing tables.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to alter this slightly for postgres (is is MS SQL syntax) but something like:

```
SELECT id
FROM   contacts
LEFT OUTER JOIN FROM case_contacts ON case_contacts.contact_id = contacts.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN FROM case_payments ON case_payments.contact_id = contacts.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN FROM invoices      ON      invoices.contact_id = contacts.id
WHERE case_contacts.contact_id IS NULL
AND   case_payments.contact_id IS NULL
AND        invoices.contact_id IS NULL
```

or:

```
SELECT id
FROM   contacts
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id FROM case_contacts)
AND    id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id FROM case_payments)
AND    id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id FROM invoices)
```

should list the IDs that are not referred to in those three tables. The query planner *should * see these as equivalent and optimise accordingly, but if not then the former will be more efficient (the latter risks running the three sub-queries once for every row in `contacts`).

Comment: Thank you. I was using something similar to your second example as a workaround (see edit at the end of the question). I don't have enough data available locally to do meaningful performance tests right now, but I should be able to do some testing after the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

For the simple result (just the `id`), **[`EXCEPT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html)** might be simplest and fastest:

Also, since you write:

> I get their primary keys in an array

Simply use [**`unnest()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and don't waste time joining to the `contacts` table:

```
SELECT id
FROM   unnest('{1,10,20,1557,5000,15057}'::int[]) id  -- actual array (not list)
EXCEPT ALL SELECT contact_id FROM case_contacts
EXCEPT ALL SELECT contact_id FROM case_payments
EXCEPT ALL SELECT contact_id FROM invoices;
```

Unless you need to verify existence, then you need the join:

```
SELECT id
FROM   unnest(arr) id
JOIN   contacts c USING (id)
EXCEPT ALL ...
```

Overview over available techniques:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

I would ***not*** suggest to use `NOT IN (subselect)`, which is typically the slowest alternative and carries traps for NULL values. Your `NOT EXISTS` variant looks perfectly fine.